# Remove docker service and wait for containers to stop

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

Let's say I have the Docker Swarm services `myservice1` and `myservice2`. How can I remove these services and wait for the associated containers to stop?

Answer (score 6):

To stop and wait for a single service:

```
$ docker service rm myservice1 && docker wait $(docker ps -f "name=myservice1" -q)
```

For multiple services:

```
$ docker service rm myservice1 myservice2 && docker wait $(docker ps -f "name=myservice1" -f "name=myservice2" -q)
```

Comment: this is only working, if the containers are on the docker-host where the command is issued. should one have multiple docker-hosts in a swarm (what swarm is intended for) this is not working anymore

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I need more rep to comment on /u/redgeoff's answer...but the `docker wait` operates on containers/tasks which are local to the node the command is executed on. In a multi-node swarm (sort of the point of using docker swarm), the node you're on isn't guaranteed to be where the service task is running.

Something like this should be better:

```
$ docker service ps --format '{{.Node}}' serviceName
# node1.swarm.internal
$ ssh user@node1.swarm.internal
$ docker service rm myservice1 && docker wait $(docker ps -f "name=serviceName" -q)
```

**However**, this *also* assumes the node the task is running on is a manager node. If it's not, then `docker service` commands cannot run. In that case, you should run the `docker service rm` command before ssh'ing into where the task exists.